# Facebook Audience Network in XAMARIN. No docs and error messages like "do not retry" and "internal error"

Tags: c#, android, facebook, xamarin, ads

I am working with Xamarin and C# and all the docs refer to Java (as usually.)

This isn't much of a problem since it is pretty easy to convert, however this time I am not able to go anywhere.

What I did so far:

- Remove Google from Project;
- Add Facebook Ads SDK (newest version);
- Add Facebook Audience Network account;
- Get my app approved;
- Put the AdID into my app.
- Write a bit of code that **should** work (according to the docs):

```cs
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

private void LoadInterstitialAd()
{
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this, "YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID");
    mInterstitialAd.SetAdListener(new AdListener());
    mInterstitialAd.LoadAd();
}

private void ButtonClick()
{
    mInterstitialAd.Show();
}

public class AdListener : Activity, IInterstitialAdListener
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnAdClicked(IAd p0)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnAdLoaded(IAd p0)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnError(IAd p0, AdError p1)
    {
        Log.Debug("y", p1.ErrorMessage);
    }

    public void OnInterstitialDismissed(IAd p0)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnInterstitialDisplayed(IAd p0)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, the code is pretty simple. But upon requesting my ad (yes, I let it load for a while before clicking `Show()`, my `adListener` class becomes active. To be more precise, before even clicking on show (but upon `load()` it throws the `OnError()` function and within the error message it just says (*and I am not kidding here:*)

```
do not retry
```

Do not retry what? This is my first try!

Upon now clicking a button to actually **show** the ad I get (*and again, I am not kidding*):

```
Internal Error
```

And this is it. All the info I get. Upon Googling those "error codes" I get nothing. No one else seems to have this issue.

I have also not found a way to test with test Interstitials, as I could with Admob.

Has anyone ever made any experience in this field? Is it my code? Do I need another NuGet package? Or do I need to set something else in my console?